# Handling conditional logic + sentinel value with mypy

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I have a function that looks roughly like this:

```
import datetime
from typing import Union

class Sentinel(object): pass
sentinel = Sentinel()

def func(
    dt: datetime.datetime,
    as_tz: Union[datetime.tzinfo, None, Sentinel] = sentinel,
) -> str:

    if as_tz is not sentinel:
        # Never reached if as_tz has wrong type (Sentinel)
        dt = dt.astimezone(as_tz)
    # ...
    # do other meaningful stuff
    # ...
    return "foo"
```

The `sentinel` value is used here because `None` is already a valid argument to `.astimezone()`, so the purpose is to correctly identify cases where the user doesn't want to call `.astimezone()` at all.

However, `mypy` complains about this pattern with:

> error: Argument 1 to "astimezone" of "datetime" has incompatible type
>   "Union[tzinfo, None, Sentinel]"; expected "Optional[tzinfo]"

It seems that's because the [`datetime` stub](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/41d6a2791a26688098be9b9eb60daee1a1ce94fc/stdlib/2and3/datetime.pyi) (rightfully so) uses:

```
def astimezone(self, tz: Optional[_tzinfo] = ...) -> datetime: ...
```

But, is there a way to let mypy know that the `sentinel` value will never be passed to `.astimezone()` because of the `if` check?  Or does this just need a `# type: ignore` with there being no cleaner way?

---

Another exampe:

```
from typing import Optional
import requests


def func(session: Optional[requests.Session] = None):
    new_session_made = session is None
    if new_session_made:
        session = requests.Session()
    try:
        session.request("GET", "https://a.b.c.d.com/foo")
        # ...
    finally:
        if new_session_made:
            session.close()
```

This second, like the first, is "runtime safe" (for lack of a better term): the `AttributeError` from calling `None.request()` and `None.close()` will not be reached or evaluated.  However, mypy still complains that:

```
mypytest.py:9: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Session]" has no attribute "request"
mypytest.py:13: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Session]" has no attribute "close"
```

Should I be doing something differently here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an explicit [`cast`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/casts.html):

```
    from typing import cast
    ... 
    if as_tz is not sentinel:
        # Never reached if as_tz has wrong type (Sentinel)
        as_tz = cast(datetime.tzinfo, as_tz)
        dt = dt.astimezone(as_tz)
```

and

```
    new_session_made = session is None
    session = cast(requests.Session, session)
```

You could alternately use an `assert` (although this is an actual runtime check whereas the `cast` is more explicitly a no-op):

```
        assert isinstance(as_tz, datetime.tzinfo)
        dt = dt.astimezone(as_tz)
```

and

```
    new_session_made = session is None
    assert session is not None
```

Answer (score 13):

In my experience, the best solution is to use `enum.Enum`.

### Requirements

A good sentinel pattern has 3 properties:

1. possesses an unambiguous type/value that cannot be mistaken for other values.  e.g. `object()`
2. can be referenced using a descriptive constant
3. can be tested concisely, using `is` and `is not`

### Solution

`enum.Enum` is treated specially by mypy such that it is the only solution I've found that can achieve all three of these requirements and also validate properly within mypy.

```
import datetime
import enum
from typing import Union

class Sentinel(enum.Enum):
    SKIP_TZ = object()

def func(
    dt: datetime.datetime,
    as_tz: Union[datetime.tzinfo, None, Sentinel] = Sentinel.SKIP_TZ,
) -> str:

    if as_tz is not Sentinel.SKIP_TZ:
        dt = dt.astimezone(as_tz)
    # ...
    # do other meaningful stuff
    # ...
    return "foo"
```

### Variations

There are a few other interesting properties to this solution.

#### Reusable Sentinel object

`sentinel.py`

```
import enum
class Sentinel(enum.Enum):
    sentinel = object()
```

`main.py`

```
import datetime
from sentinel import Sentinel
from typing import Union

SKIP_TZ = Sentinel.sentinel

def func(
    dt: datetime.datetime,
    as_tz: Union[datetime.tzinfo, None, Sentinel] = SKIP_TZ,
) -> str:

    if as_tz is not SKIP_TZ:
        dt = dt.astimezone(as_tz)
    # ...
    # do other meaningful stuff
    # ...
    return "foo"
```

Note that due to the fact that `Sentinel.sentinel` always provides the same `object` instance, two reusable sentinels should never be used the same context.

#### Restrict Sentinel value using `Literal`

Replacing `Sentinel` with `Literal[Sentinel.SKIP_TZ]]` adds further clarity to your function signature, though it is admittedly superfluous, since there is only one enum value.

```
import datetime
import enum
from typing import Union
from typing_extensions import Literal

class Sentinel(enum.Enum):
    SKIP_TZ = object()

def func(
    dt: datetime.datetime,
    as_tz: Union[datetime.tzinfo, None, Literal[Sentinel.SKIP_TZ]] = Sentinel.SKIP_TZ,
) -> str:

    if as_tz is not Sentinel.SKIP_TZ:
        dt = dt.astimezone(as_tz)
    # ...
    # do other meaningful stuff
    # ...
    return "foo"

func(datetime.datetime.now(), as_tz=Sentinel.SKIP_TZ)
```

### Solutions that did not meet my requirements

#### Custom sentinel class

```
import datetime
from typing import Union

class SentinelType:
    pass

SKIP_TZ = SentinelType()


def func(
    dt: datetime.datetime,
    as_tz: Union[datetime.tzinfo, None, SentinelType] = SKIP_TZ,
) -> str:

    if not isinstance(dt, SentinelType):
        dt = dt.astimezone(as_tz)
    # ...
    # do other meaningful stuff
    # ...
    return "foo"
```

While this works, using `isinstance(dt, SentinelType)` fails requirement 3 ("use `is`"), and thus also requirement 2 ("use named constant").  For clarity, I want to be able to use `if dt is not SKIP_TZ`.

#### object `Literal`

`Literal` does not work with arbitrary values (though it does work with enums. see above.)

```
import datetime
from typing import Union
from typing_extensions import Literal

SKIP_TZ = object()

def func(
    dt: datetime.datetime,
    as_tz: Union[datetime.tzinfo, None, Literal[SKIP_TZ]] = SKIP_TZ,
) -> str:

    if dt is SKIP_TZ:
        dt = dt.astimezone(as_tz)
    # ...
    # do other meaningful stuff
    # ...
    return "foo"
```

Produces the following mypy errors:

```
error: Parameter 1 of Literal[...] is invalid
error: Variable "sentinel.SKIP_TZ" is not valid as a type
```

#### String `Literal`

In this attempt, I used a string literal instead of an object:

```
import datetime
from typing import Union
from typing_extensions import Literal


def func(
    dt: datetime.datetime,
    as_tz: Union[datetime.tzinfo, None, Literal['SKIP_TZ']] = 'SKIP_TZ',
) -> str:

    if as_tz is not 'SKIP_TZ':
        dt = dt.astimezone(as_tz)
    # ...
    # do other meaningful stuff
    # ...
    return "foo"

func(datetime.datetime.now(), as_tz='SKIP_TZ')
```

Even if this worked, it would be pretty weak on requirement 1.

But it doesn't pass in mypy.  It produces the error:

```
error: Argument 1 to "astimezone" of "datetime" has incompatible type "Union[tzinfo, None, Literal['SKIP_TZ']]"; expected "Optional[tzinfo]"
```

Comment: Thanks! This enum solution also works with pytype.

Answer (score 2):

One way to bypass this issue is by doing something like this:

```
from typing import Optional
import requests


def func(session: Optional[requests.Session] = None) -> None:
    new_session = session is None
    if not session:
        session = requests.Session()
    try:
        session.request("GET", "https://a.b.c.d.com/foo")
        # other stuff
    finally:
        if not new_session:
            session.close()
```

Also, we can check if `mypy` can handle the cases where we use different argument types:

```
func('a')  # mypy_typing.py:14: error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Optional[Session]"
func(1)  # mypy_typing.py:14: error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Optional[Session]"
...
# PS:  The test will break for any kind of types except for None and requests.Session
...
```

But if we use `None` or `request.Session()` objects as arguments the test passes without any errors:

```
func(None)  # No errors
func(requests.Session())  # No errors
```

For more informations you can read this [example](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#optional-types-and-the-none-type) from `mypy`'s official documentation.

Comment: Small problem here - the purpose of `new_session_made` is to *only* close the session if none was passed by the caller.  The point is to not modify the state of an open TCP session that is passed if the caller doesn't want it to be closed within the function.

Comment: @BradSolomon Damn, i skipped this information. I've updated my answer and test it. It goes well into the `if not new_session` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Mypy has special handling for `isinstance`. Instead of checking for identity it is possible to do:

```
if not isinstance(as_tz, Sentinel):
    dt = dt.astimezone(as_tz)

...
```

with this change your example seems to typecheck.